# Knockout 2.1.0 Inconsistency with "if" binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a strange inconsistency using the **if** binding to hide/show a button.

I need to add a button to an ASP.NET page that already uses Knockoutjs. The code for the button is:

```
<!-- ko if: (EnableButton()) -->
<div id="pnlBtnGoToRiepilogoIncasso" style="display: inline;">
  <asp:Button ID="btnGoToRiepilogoIncasso" CssClass="btn" Text="&#8250; Incassa" runat="server" type="submit" />
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I have created a Knockout observable like this:

```
self.EnableButton = ko.observable(false);
```

and in the success callback of an Ajax call made with JQuery I change it's value like this:

```
self.EnableButton(true);
```

The problem is that the behavior is inconsistent, it sometimes displays the button and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't I check its value in the console and it its correct.

Sometimes it happens also if I change the value of the observable manually.

Do you have any insights on why this happens? is there something related to the version I'm using?

Thank you

Comment: You should at least change `ko if: (EnableButton())` to `ko if: EnableButton`

Comment: Alas the "inconsistent" behavior, and the "sometimes..." bits means you/we lack a way to reproduce the behavior, and can only guess at the problem and solution. You'll need to do the root cause analysis yourself I'm afraid, and get back to us with a wee bit more code (enough to reproduce the problem).

Comment: You need to show the failing code. KO works perfectly, so you must be doing something wrong somewhere else. If you don't show the real problem, this question shpuld be closed.

Comment: Check the console to see if there are any errors when rendering